# very large value of loss in AlexNet

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

Actually I am using AlexNet to classify my images in 2 groups , I am feeding images to the model in a batch of 60 images and the loss which I am getting after every batch is 6 to 7 digits large
 (for ex. 1428529.0) , here I am confused that why my loss is such a large value because on MNIST dataset the loss which I got was very small as compared to this. Can anyone explain me why I am getting such a large loss value.
Thanks in advance ;-)

Here is the code :-

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

img_size = 227
num_channels = 1
img_flat_size = img_size * img_size 
num_classes = 2
drop = 0.5

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,img_flat_size])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,num_classes])
drop_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def new_weight(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape))

def new_bias(size):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(size))

def new_conv(x,num_input_channels,filter_size,num_filters,stride,padd="SAME"):
    shape = [filter_size,filter_size,num_input_channels,num_filters]

    weight = new_weight(shape)
    bias = new_bias([num_filters])

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x,weight,strides=[1,stride,stride,1],padding=padd)

    conv = tf.nn.bias_add(conv,bias)

    return tf.nn.relu(conv)

def new_max_pool(x,k,stride):
    max_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=[1,k,k,1],strides=[1,stride,stride,1],padding="VALID")
    return max_pool

def flatten_layer(layer):
    layer_shape = layer.get_shape()
    num_features = layer_shape[1:4].num_elements()

    flat_layer = tf.reshape(layer,[-1,num_features])

    return flat_layer,num_features

def new_fc_layer(x,num_input,num_output):
    weight = new_weight([num_input,num_output])
    bias = new_bias([num_output])

    fc_layer = tf.matmul(x,weight) + bias

    return fc_layer

def lrn(x, radius, alpha, beta, bias=1.0):
    """Create a local response normalization layer."""
    return tf.nn.local_response_normalization(x, depth_radius=radius,
                                              alpha=alpha, beta=beta,
                                              bias=bias)


def AlexNet(x,drop,img_size):
    x = tf.reshape(x,shape=[-1,img_size,img_size,1])

    conv1 = new_conv(x,num_channels,11,96,4,"VALID")
    max_pool1 = new_max_pool(conv1,3,2)
    norm1 = lrn(max_pool1, 2, 2e-05, 0.75)

    conv2 = new_conv(norm1,96,5,256,1)
    max_pool2 = new_max_pool(conv2,3,2)
    norm2 = lrn(max_pool2, 2, 2e-05, 0.75)    

    conv3 = new_conv(norm2,256,3,384,1)

    conv4 = new_conv(conv3,384,3,384,1)

    conv5 = new_conv(conv4,384,3,256,1)

    max_pool3 = new_max_pool(conv5,3,2)

    layer , num_features = flatten_layer(max_pool3)

    fc1 = new_fc_layer(layer,num_features,4096)
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1,drop)

    fc2 = new_fc_layer(fc1,4096,4096)
    fc2 = tf.nn.relu(fc2)
    fc2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc2,drop)

    out = new_fc_layer(fc2,4096,2)

    return out #, tf.nn.softmax(out)

def read_and_decode(tfrecords_file, batch_size):
    '''read and decode tfrecord file, generate (image, label) batches
    Args:
        tfrecords_file: the directory of tfrecord file
        batch_size: number of images in each batch
    Returns:
        image: 4D tensor - [batch_size, width, height, channel]
        label: 1D tensor - [batch_size]
    '''
    # make an input queue from the tfrecord file
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([tfrecords_file])

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    img_features = tf.parse_single_example(
                                        serialized_example,
                                        features={
                                               'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                               'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                               })
    image = tf.decode_raw(img_features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)

    ##########################################################
    # you can put data augmentation here, I didn't use it
    ##########################################################
    # all the images of notMNIST are 28*28, you need to change the image size if you use other dataset.

    image = tf.reshape(image, [227, 227])
    label = tf.cast(img_features['label'], tf.int32)    
    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label],
                                                batch_size= batch_size,
                                                num_threads= 1, 
                                                capacity = 6000)
    return tf.reshape(image_batch,[batch_size,227*227*1]), tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size])

pred  = AlexNet(x,drop_p,img_size) #pred

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred,labels=y))

optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001).minimize(loss)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred,tf.float32))

cost = tf.summary.scalar('loss',loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    merge_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./AlexNet',graph = tf.get_default_graph())

    tf_record_file = 'train.tfrecords'
    x_val ,y_val = read_and_decode(tf_record_file,20)
    y_val = tf.one_hot(y_val,depth=2,on_value=1,off_value=0)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    x_val = x_val.eval()
    y_val = y_val.eval()
    epoch = 2
    for i in range(epoch):
        _, summary= sess.run([optimiser,merge_summary],feed_dict={x:x_val,y:y_val,drop_p:drop})
        summary_writer.add_summary(summary,i)
        loss_a,accu = sess.run([loss,accuracy],feed_dict={x:x_val,y:y_val,drop_p:1.0})
        print "Epoch "+str(i+1) +', Minibatch Loss = '+ \
            "{:.6f}".format(loss_a) + ', Training Accuracy = '+ \
            '{:.5f}'.format(accu)

    print "Optimization Finished!"

    tf_record_file1 = 'test.tfrecords'
    x_v ,y_v = read_and_decode(tf_record_file1,10)
    y_v = tf.one_hot(y_v,depth=2,on_value=1,off_value=0)
    coord1 = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads1 = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord1)
    x_v = sess.run(x_v)
    y_v = sess.run(y_v)
    print "Testing Accuracy : "
    print sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:x_v,y:y_v,drop_p:1.0})

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    coord1.request_stop()
    coord1.join(threads1)
```

Comment: Is the loss decreasing?. Without looking at your code snippet its not easy to figure out whats going wrong.

Comment: @vijaym I have uploaded the code

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a what a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) is. It is a performance evaluator. In addition, you should  compare your precision versus your recall. Precision is the accuracy of your positive predictions and recall is the ratio of positive instances that are correctly detected by the classifier. By combining both precision and recall, you get the [F_1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) which is keep in evaluating the problems of your model.

I would suggest you pick up the text *Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow*. It is a truly comprehensive book and covers what I describe above in more detail.